# Removing matching regex from file name

Tags: regular-expression

I am owner of Radio Station, and I have over 5000 tracks on my Cent OS PC.
They are named like this

```
01. Craig David - Love Yourself (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
01. The Maccabees - Hello (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
02. Lukas Graham - 7 Years (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
02. The Weeknd - Can't Feel My Face (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
03. Blonde - Work - Pillowtalk - Children (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
03. Olly Murs - Can't Stop the Feeling - Rock Your Body (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
04. Coldplay - Adventure of a Lifetime (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
04. One Direction - Four Five Seconds (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
05. Jonas Blue - Hotter Than Hell (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
05. Nick Jonas - Lush Life (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
06. Fifth Harmony - Ex's & Oh's (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
06. Jack Garratt - Worry (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
07. Lower Than Atlantis - On My Mind (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
07. Usher - Crash (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
08. Gorgon City - One Dance (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
08. Grace - You Don't Own Me (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
09. Dua Lipa - The Hills (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
09. Mike Posner - In Ibiza (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
10. DNCE - Hands to Myself (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
10. Shawn Mendes - Stitches (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
11. James Bay - Hymn for the Weekend (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
11. Karen Harding - PILLOWTALK (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
12. The 1975 - Sorry (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
12. Tom Odell - The Sound (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
13. Alessia Cara - Hotline Bling (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
13. Birdy - Fast Car (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
14. Jamie Lawson - Wasn't Expecting That (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
14. M.O - How Will I Know - Perfect Strangers (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
15. CHVRCHES - This Is What You Came For (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
15. Kygo - Wildest Dreams (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
16. Bastille - 7 Days - Final Song (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
16. Fleur East - Sax (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
17. Biffy Clyro - (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
17. Blossoms - In2 (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
18. Charlie Puth - We Don't Talk Anymore (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
18. Izzy Bizu - White Tiger (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
19. Clean Bandit - Work from Home (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
19. Laura Mvula - New Person, Same Old Mistakes (Live from BBC Radio's Live Lounge).mp3
```

I want to remove `01.` from file names.
I found a several same questions as mine, and no answer works for me in my centos 7 installation.

```
/^\d\d. /g
```

This is regex i came up with and it matches when i test it here

http://regexr.com/

But i have absolutely no idea how to implement it with sed, or find with rename.
It's really blowing my mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '<->. (*)' '$1'
```

Remove `-n` when happy.

`<x-y>` matches decimal number between `x` and `y`. `<->` is any number.

Comment: This is my first time i am facing ZSH.
This worked like charm, may I ask how do i exit from "ZSH" whatever that is.

Comment: I just entered BASH and i was back.
Thanks again

Comment: `exit` to exit. Like in `bash`. `zsh` is another Bourne-like shell.

Answer (score 1):

A solution in only `sed` and `sh`:

```sh
for FILE in *.mp3
do mv "$FILE" "$(echo $FILE | sed -r 's/^[[:digit:]]{2}\. //g')"
done
```

Comment: i'll stick to zsh for now :D
I do not want to "risk" anymore.
Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

To just chop off the first four characters from a filename:

```
for fpath in path/to/songs/*.mp3; do
  fname="${fpath##*/}"
  newname="${fname:4}"
  echo mv "${fpath}" "${fpath%/*}"/"$newname"
done
```

Remove the `echo` once you are sure it's doing the right thing.